# Affine space over algebraically closed field cannot be written as a finite union of lines.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and $\mathbb{A}^n=\{(a_1,\dots,a_n):a_i\in k\}$ be an affine space. I want to show that $\mathbb{A}^n$ cannot be written as a finite union of lines where $k$ is algebraically closed for $n>1$.

By contradiction: let $\mathbb{A}^n=l_1\cup\dots\cup l_n$ where $l_i$ is the line in $\mathbb{A}^n$ ($l_i$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{A}^n$). Then we get a contradiction since $\mathbb{A}^n$ is an irreducible topological space, so it cannot be written as a finite union of proper non-empty closed subsets.

However, I am confused if I need $k$ to be algebraically closed. I know $k$ must to be infinite for sure since $\mathbb{A}^n$ is a finite set over a finite field $k$. Also, do we even consider $\mathbb{A}^n$ to be irreducible in that case i.e. $k$ is a finite field?

Comment: You haven't defined $\Bbb A^n$, and one thing people frequently mean by this, $\operatorname{Spec} k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$, never has finitely many points no matter what field $k$ is. Can you add your definition?

Comment: @KReiser I think about $\mathbb{A}^n$ naively as a set of $n$-tuples with entries in $k$.

Comment: Then it may be helpful to write out your definition of "line", and define what it means to be distinct with respect to this definition. I think it will then become clear where to use the fact that $k$ is algebraically closed, and in particular, infinite.

Answer (score 1):

The hypothesis $k$ algebraically closed is redundant. $k$ infinite is enough to get the result.

We can even prove the stronger result that an affine space $E$ over an infinite field $k$ can’t be the finite union of proper affine subspaces $E_1, \dots E_n$. Considering the underlying linear subspaces, it is enough to prove the similar result for linear subspaces.

For the proof we  denote $F_i= E_1 \cup \dots E_i$ and proceed by induction. The result is clear for $n=1$ as $E_1$ is supposed to be a proper linear subspace.

Suppose that $n \ge 2$ and assume by contradiction that $E=F_n$. According to induction hypothesis, $E\neq F_{n-1}$. So it exists $x \in E \setminus F_{n-1}$. Let also $y$ be in $E \setminus E_n$.

The map $u : k \to E$ defined by $u(\lambda)= \lambda x +y$ is taking values in $F_{n-1}$ as $\lambda x +y \in E_n$ implies $y \in E_n$. As $k$ is supposed to be infinite, it exists $\alpha \neq \beta$ and $j \le n-1$ such that $u(\alpha),u(\beta) \in E_j$. This leads to the contradiction

$$x =(\alpha-\beta)^{-1}(u(\alpha)-u(\beta)) \in E_j.$$

Comment: I think you can simplify this greatly by working in coordinates and sticking with lines instead of affine subspaces. Or, go directly to your last step: the lines are assumed distinct, so let $x \in E_i$ and $y \in E_j$ for $i\neq j$. Keep the mapping $u$, and take $\alpha \neq \beta \in k$ (using $k$ is infinite), and you get the contradiction $x = y$ using your same trick.

Comment: @DerekAllums I went to affine subspaces rather than lines on purpose as it is more general. And I don't see how to avoid the induction as I made the hypothesis $E \neq F_{n-1}$. What's your idea?

Comment: Re. induction I think you're right. I misread and am slightly confused at the last step, in particular don't you mean $y = (\alpha - \beta)^{-1}(u(\alpha)-u(\beta))$ and not $x$? And why is $x+\lambda y$ in $F_{n-1}$? You assumed $x \in E \setminus F_{n-1}$. Maybe some clarification on the last bit would be helpful (at least to me).

Comment: Some updates in order to clarify.

Comment: Ok I wrote it out and filled in some small details - I think the problem is a typo in your definition of $u$: shouldn't it be $\lambda x + y$ rather than $x + \lambda y$? As it's written, you assume $y\in F_{n-1}$ and thus in some $E_j$ for $j \leq n-1$ by assumptions, then in your last line show $y \in E_j$, which is not a contradiction. But if you move the $\lambda$ and keep your assumptions, then you have $x \in E_n$, but by your same trick end up with $x \in F_{n-1}$, which is a contradiction.